# Laravel - Bug in sending email to wrong user

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, laravel-5.1, beanstalkd

I'm using laravel 5.1. AWS EC2 service, ubuntu OS.

I've created a command that sends emails to a number of users. Lets say I have this sample code:

```
foreach($users as $user) {
    $data = $user->toArray();
    $data['subject'] = "This is subject";
    Mail::queue('emails.email_content', $data, function ($message) use ($data) {
        $message->subject($data['subject']);
        $message->to($data['email']);
    });
}
```

In `email_content.blade.php` lets say I have this code

```
Hi {{ $first_name . ' ' . $last_name }}
```

I used beanstalkd as my queue driver. And use supervisor for monitoring.
In my .env file I have this:

```
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=database
QUEUE_DRIVER=beanstalkd
```

But some users are complaining that they're receiving the wrong emails because the name is wrong, sometimes even the subject is wrong. And I'm sure getting the correct `$users`. What am I doing wrong here? Is it possible that the email are cached or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem has been resolved, it seems that I have to run `php artisan queue:restart` whenever I changed my email view content.